# LPC1768 - Green LED when LDR sees light, Red LED when LDR is covered

Tags: led, c, light, ldr, lpc1768

I have been trying to achieve a task I am working on and I believe I am almost there. It successfully changes colors whenever I cover it but when it does, the red LED keeps blinking instead of it remaining open in a constant manner.

```
void Task5(TestAdmin &tester, PwmOut &r_led, PwmOut &g_led, AnalogIn &ldr)
{
    while(tester.testRunning()) {
        g_led.write(1); //turn off
        r_led.write(1); // turn off

        float value = ldr.read(); //takes the reading from the LDR(Light Dependent Resistor)

        if(value >= 0.4) {
            r_led.write(0); //turn on
        } else {
            g_led.write(0); // turn on
            wait_ms(2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK. Formatted code posted. Now why the two `write(1);` statements? Add in some code comments to explain your logic.

Comment: It might be wise to put a minimum of effort into understanding your tools, such as which programming language and MCU you are actually using. You are programming C++, not C. You are using floating point on a MCU without FPU. Etc. This will in turn enable you to understand why your program is so slow when you inevitably run into performance bottlenecks later down the road.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a full answer but there seem to be a few problems with your code. 
You use

```
g_led.write(1);
```

and further down

```
green.write(0);
```

Should `green` be `g_led`?

Your routine also turns both LEDs on on each call to Task5 and then if `value >= 0.4` turns the red off again. That may explain your blinking.

As pointed out in the comment, sloppy indentation doesn't help in trying to debug this. Get into the habit of always indenting your code properly as you go.

---

Try this:

```
while(tester.testRunning()) {
    float value = ldr.read(); //takes the reading from the LDR(Light Dependent Resistor)

    if(value >= 0.4) {
        g_led.write(1); // Green off.
        r_led.write(0); // Red on.
    } else {
        g_led.write(0); // Green on.
        r_led.write(1); // Red off.
        //wait_ms(2);   // not required
    }
}
```